# How to implement subnet for existing home network

Tags: subnet

This is really a nooby question about subnetting. I understand the basic concept behind subnets but I really don't know exactly how to implement it.

For me, I would like to have 4 subnets and from what I understand my submask would be 255.255.255.192:

desktop computers phones tv/roku everything else Modem/Router Model: Arris BGW210-700

Example IP: 192.168.1.0

How would I actually implement this so that certain devices will be on their corresponding subnet?

Do I need any additional equipment?

If at all, can someone show me to some kind of guide or article on implementation?

Comment: You can get a somewhat advanced switch that will allow you to create 4 VLANs (4 subnets).  That should work. The question is Why?  You do not have enough stuff to warrant 4 subnets, and then if you do this, devices will be isolated from each other. That is normally not a good idea.

Comment: @John Thanks for the info. Makes sense